# Cant add the same js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have two of this gallery on one html page... but i cant just recopy the code. i belive i would need to make some other div id for this to work... i want to have one gallery show my youtube channel and another showing another youtube channel.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="http://files.enjin.com/469593/Styles/ytv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://files.enjin.com/469593/Styles/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="frame">
</div>

<!--Change user to your channel-->
<script>
window.onload = function(){
window.controller = new YTV('frame', {
user: 'midnightmafiaGUILD',
accent: 'yellow'
});

};
</script>

<div id="frame">
</div>

<!--Change user to your channel-->
<script>
window.onload = function(){
window.controller = new YTV('frame', {
user: 'other youtube channel',
accent: 'yellow'
});

};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.enjin.com/469593/Styles/ytv.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included the [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js) library in the header?

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the external script first.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.enjin.com/469593/Styles/ytv.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
window.controller = new YTV('frame', {
user: 'midnightmafiaGUILD',
playlist: 'PLdxzlBKS1wMV2fjkYR9GA2f3t0R4CAof8',
accent: 'yellow'
});

};
</script>
```

Comment: what i want to do is use it twice. i want to add two galleries to my website and it doesent seem to let me. i tried changing the frame div tag to something else and also changing it were it says new YTV('frame')

Comment: @HenryPerez That is you need two different video player in one page. Am I correct? Then I think, you can't do it with current [library](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Youtube-TV/src/ytv.js). From quick look on youtube js, I think, it handles only one gallery on each page load.

Comment: im sorry im kinda new to all this... basically i want to have two of the same gallery. one showing my youtube channel and another showing a friends. i belive i would need to change the div ID or something along those lines. i need a way to duplicate the gallery without it affecting the original one

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `youtube js` first then use it like,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.enjin.com/469593/Styles/ytv.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        window.controller = new YTV('frame', {
            user: 'midnightmafiaGUILD',
            playlist: 'PLdxzlBKS1wMV2fjkYR9GA2f3t0R4CAof8',
            accent: 'yellow'
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: what i want to do is use it twice. i want to add two galleries to my website and it doesent seem to let me. i tried changing the frame div tag to something else and also changing it were it says new YTV('frame')